# Keep text positions after saving richtextbox to RTF file

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox, rtf

i'm trying to create some RTF files from richtextbox content ( which is load from RTF files )
After opening file by some code and applying some changes and saving back new file (output) to another location. i find that positions text have changed and also font colors. please see attached captures for more clarifications.
input:

[image: input]

output:
[image: output]

desired ouput

[image]

I think i need to talk a bit about what i apply to input from the code: well i need to replace every variables begining by $ by some variables from databases:

I used this portion of code for that:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, "(\\$\\w+)"))
                    {
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add1"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getAdress1(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add2"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getAdress2(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add3"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getAdress3(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add4"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getLand(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Rechnr"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, nums_res[j]);
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Datum"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getDatum(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("resname"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getName1(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("resvorname"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getVorname(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("resroom"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getZimmer(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                        if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("anz"))
                            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(match.Groups[1].Value, getAnz(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                    }

                    int indexToText = richTextBox1.Find(getAdress1(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                    int endIndex = richTextBox1.Find(getAdress1(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                    if(indexToText > 0 && endIndex > 0)
                        richTextBox1.Select(indexToText, endIndex); richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

                    int indexToText2 = richTextBox1.Find(getLand(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                    int endIndex2 = richTextBox1.Find(getLand(nums_res[j].ToString()));
                    if (indexToText2 > 0 && endIndex2 > 0)
                        richTextBox1.Select(indexToText2, endIndex2);  richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile("d:\\ryadmogadoroutput" + nums_res[j].ToString());
                    i = i + 1;
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
```

for now i dont replace all of them but just some and i want to know where the difference comes between my output and desired output. ( as u can see, i tried to center first variables from the code)

i'm wondering if theres a way to keep original format of the file after applying the changed i talked about

Thank you

EDIT: After changing the property .text to rtf here the improved output. still some details to fix: font color, and some deplaced ( i dont know why ) strings, please see date:$datum
[image]

EDIT: solution suggestion by @TaW:
output:
[image]

compilation error:
[image]

Comment: Please also doublecheck your formatting: `..SelectionAlignment ..` __looks__ as if you are missing a pair of braces, twice..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you should change the text format to RTF Format by changing "richTextBox1.Text" to "richTextBox1.RTF"

Comment: Thank you a lot! it worked.. well still the font color is blue ( not like original wich is black ) but i will figure out how to fix that later... thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You must **never** change the `Text` directly after **any** formatting has been applied to the RichText. Instead you need to work strictly on the `SelectedText` using `Copy`, `Paste`, `Append` and the other specialized methods.

So at the very least you need to write an appropriate `Replace` function!

Maybe, with a little luck, not working on the `Text` but the `Rtf` property will also help, but it may be interwoven with formatting stuff that might be in the way..

Here is a function that will to do it :

```
void RtfReplace(RichTextBox RTB, Match match, string replace,  ref int offset)
{
    RTB.Select(match.Index + offset, match.Length);
    RTB.SelectedText = replace;
    offset += replace.Length - match.Length;
}
```

And a few respective calls

```
int offset = 0;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, "(\\$\\w+)"))
{
    if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add1"))
        RtfReplace(richTextBox1, match, getAdress1(nums_res[j].ToString()), ref offset); 
    if (match.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1).Equals("Add2"))
        RtfReplace(richTextBox1, match, getAdress2(nums_res[j].ToString()), ref offset); 
    //..
```

**Update**: Since each replacement is likely to change the length of the replaced piece of text we will need to adjust all positions in the matches collection by that difference (or repeatedly call the whole replacement code until no more matches are found.) The fix is simple, though..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, the process i want to realize is to look for those special variables ($add1) and replace them by reading each line.. that why i replace while browsing for them ( replace in the body of the for each ) is there a better way.. the solution you provide me Dotnetter worked ( replacing .text by .rtf ) but for some reason the font color is still blue and some unorganized formating.. please see image in the edited post

Comment: Well, look again, my answer will do just what you want: Simply replace the old code (`richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace( match.Groups[1].Value, getAdress1( nums_res[j].ToString()));`) with a version like the one I showed you for the 1st two lines, for all your searchstrings! This will keep the formatting, colors and the fonts. (And, unrelated to the probelms, do either add those missing braces or change the formatting, so that the lines with `..SelectionAlignment ..` don't look so wrong!)

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it does not replace some variables and some strings change their place.. please see outputstack ( catpure after applying your suggestion )

Comment: Hm, this is not what I see here, but of course I don't have you data. If the color still is messed up then you still must do something to the Text directly. Please make sure that you don't do that at all. - The alignment code was ok, so it should not change. I don't know why some variable get changed and some don't. Maybe some typo has slipped in?

Comment: I have no idea.. when i open those files with word font color is still black but placement is a bit messed up.. maybe some margins issue ? since some variables goes to the next line.. i dont know :/

Comment: I have found a stupid error of mine, please check out the fix!

Comment: This throws a compilation error.. please see capture in my post and thank you for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64876/discussion-between-user2233979-and-taw).